# Is "Locked Up Abroad" filmed at real locations?

Tags: film-location, locked-up-abroad

The show Locked Up Abroad features realistic scenes of foreign jails and police stations in dangerous countries [like Venezuela](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH1W4fIQRQQ). I know it is expensive to film on location, and getting a film crew into barios and prisons in places like Nicaragua and Venezuela would seem to be difficult and dangerous. Are these scenes actually shot on location, or are they staged in the UK/USA?

Answer (score 1):

**Primarily they are shot on a set or external US/UK location substituting for the real place.**

Although, on occasions, we do see partipants returning to the location of their incarceration these are more "reminiscence" vists than recreations on actual location.

There us a brief "behind the scenes" video on youtube showing such a prision recreation being filmed.

For specials a substitute location (Morocco for Turkey for instance) might be used as in this example